# PostgreSQL 9.3 : Convert `DD-MM-YYYY` into `YYYY-MM-DD`

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following date which is of varchar type to convert into format `YYYY-MM-DD` in my function.

I am passing v_Date as a parameter to the function and within function want to perfrom the conversion.

**Script**:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE v_Date varchar := '16-01-2010 00:00:00';
    v_SQL varchar;
BEGIN
    v_SQL := 'SELECT to_date('''|| v_Date ||''',''YYYY-MM-DD'')';

    RAISE INFO '%',v_SQL;

    EXECUTE v_SQL;
END;
$$
```

The above script prepare the following script:

```
INFO:  SELECT to_date('16-01-2010 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Which gives me the result:

```
0021-07-02
```

But the expected result should be:

```
2010-01-16
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> SELECT to_date('16-01-2010 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD')

Your pattern `yyyy-mm-dd` does not match the input `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss`. You need to use `dd-mm-yyyy` to convert that input to a proper date (you can leave out the additional time part)

```
SELECT to_date('16-01-2010 00:00:00','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

The formatted output of a `date` value is up to your SQL client and (or) the current settings for LC_TIME. To make sure you get the `yyyy-mm-dd` output you have to format the resulting `date` using `to_char()`

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('16-01-2010 00:00:00','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```